# How to locally echo Apply task?

Tags: ant, apply

Is it possible to execute an apply on a file set and have ant print the command it is executing?

For example:

```
<target name="test">
    <apply executable="ls" failonerror="true" verbose="true" ignoremissing="false">
        <fileset dir=".">
            <include name="*.xml" />
        </fileset>

        <arg line="-la" />
    </apply>
</target>
```

I would like the output to be something close to the following, with the key line being:

> `[apply] ls -la ./build.xml"`

E.g.

```
Buildfile: /home/abarker/NetBeansProjects/TestProject/build.xml
test:
    [apply] ls -la ./build.xml
    [apply] -rw-r--r-- 1 abarker abarker 29231 Feb 13 11:29 /home/abarker/NetBeansProjects/TestProject/build.xml
    [apply] Applied ls to 1 file and 0 directories.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ideas I have:

- You can use the `outputproperty` parameter. This will give you the output of the command in the `<apply>` task.
- You can use fileset reference instead of an actual fileset.

Like this:

```
<property name="apply.files.prop" refid='apply.files'/>
<echo>The files you're operating on are "${apply.files.prop}"</echo>

<apply executable="ls" failonerror="true" verbose="true" ignoremissing="false">
    <fileset refid="apply.files"/>
    <arg line="-la" />
</apply>
```

You can then look at the fileset reference `apply.files` to see what files the `<apply>` task is operating on.

You can always add the `-debug` and `-verbose` flag when you run ant. This will print exactly what you want and then some -- then some a whole lot. I wish there was a way to turn verbose mode on and off on a particular task, but I don't know how to do that -- [at least an easy way to do that](http://codefeed.com/blog/changing-ant-log-levels).

Comment: Hi David, may you elaborate it a little more for someone who is not particularly skilled with ant?

Answer (score 0):

For debug purposes - Just replace your own executable with echo. Here is an example of how I do it on Windows machines:

```
  <target name="test">
    <apply executable="cmd" failonerror="true" verbose="true" ignoremissing="false">
        <fileset dir=".">
            <include name="*.xml" />
        </fileset>

        <arg line="/c" />
        <arg line="echo" />
        <arg line="ls" />
        <arg line="-la" />
    </apply>
  </target>
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally when you run `ant` with `-v`/`-verbose` flag, it will print each execution of the command (this also includes `exec` and `apply`).